# How do i update object in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I would like to update an object in the middle of processing redux I need to check if this is first time for a function.

here is my code.

```
const initialState = {
  table: [],
  timer: 0,
  result: "",
  gameState: false,
  openedCount: 0,
  isFirst: true
};
```

what I tried

```
if(state.isFirst) {
   state.isFirst = false;
}
```

How do I update like that in redux? just want to update for isFirst not returning state.

I will return { ...state, table: newArray }

I would really appreciate your help thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Assuming this is inside a reducer, you `return { ...state, isFirst: false }` - similar to what you've shown with `newArray` below.

Answer (score -2):

you can write this condition :

```
if(state.isFirst) {
   state.isFirst = false;
}
```

in each switch case :
and update your state accordingly .

For example :

```
const initialState = {
  table: [],
  timer: 0,
  result: "",
  gameState: false,
  openedCount: 0,
  isFirst: true
};
const Reducer(state=initialState,action)=>{
   switch(action.type){
      case "first" : 
           if(state.isFirst) {
              state.isFirst = false;
              // update the new state
           }       
      case "second" : 
           if(state.isFirst) {
              state.isFirst = false;
              // update the new state
           }   
      default : return;        
   }
}
```